# Getting error message: "Whoops: didn't find expected signature 

Tags: android, android-emulator, centos, adb

I have been getting this error message upon installing a simple APK to the emulator using adb installation command: adb install

Error Message:

```
[root@localhost MobileBenchmark]# cd /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
[root@localhost platform-tools]# adb install JotaTextEditor.apk
Whoops: didn't find expected signature
read_central_directory_entry failed
file 'JotaTextEditor.apk' is not a valid zip file
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/JotaTextEditor.apk, No such file or directory
```

I am using Linux CentOS, latest Android SDK and emulator: Platform 4.1, API Level: 16.

What could be the problem? Please help!

Comment: Do you already have this application installed in emulator? I suggest you either remove already installed application by going to Setting app or use the command "adb uninstall <package-name>. Try again after doing this.

Comment: I suggest you upvote my answer when I put it up.

Comment: I did put up my answer. You will have to accept the answer now.

Comment: I found out that the APKs are corrupted. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: How did you find it was corrupted?  What did you do to fix it?  Having a corruption issue here also I think.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have this application installed in emulator? I suggest you either remove already installed application by going to Setting app or use the command `"adb uninstall <package-name>."` Try again after doing this.